# escribir en un edit text y que automaticamente se refleje en un edittext

Tags: android

Voy a comenzar un nuevo proyecto, en el cual el usuario escribe en un edittext y automaticamente lo que pone se ve reflejado en el textview.

Se os ocurre alguna manera de llevarlo a cabo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haciendo uso de [TextWatcher:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

```
tuEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(editText.getText().length() >= 0) {
            tuTextView.setText(editText.getText().toString())
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Buena respuesta solo yo cambiaría if(editText.getText().length() >= 0) {
            tuTextView.setText(editText.getText().toString())
        }  por esto: if (s.length() >= 0) {
                    tuTextView.setText(s.toString());
                }

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta es por medio de **[TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)** y simplemente se valida que la longitud del texto introducido en el `EditText` sea diferente de 0 para agregar el texto en el `TextView`.

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0)
         myTextView.setText(myEditText.getText().toString());
   }
  });
```